# jQuery sliding width function consistently shrinking input in Chrome, working correctly in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

Why does this simple function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input:not([type="checkbox"], .button, .noanimate)').focus(function() {
    $(this).stop(true, true).animate({
        width: $(this).width() + 50,
    }, 300);
  });

  $('input:not([type="checkbox"], .button, .noanimate)').focusout(function() {
    $(this).stop(true, true).animate({
        width: $(this).width() - 50,
    }, 300);
  });
});
```

affecting this input element:

```
#search input {
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 24px;
  margin: 5px 0 0 0;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #003F80;
  background-color: #4682c6;
  color: #F5F5F5;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 5px #003F80, 0 1px 3px #73ACE5;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}
```

Work correctly in Firefox & Opera, but not in Chrome?  In the former browsers, when the input is in focus, its width expands from it's default 300px to 350px, and when focus is removed, the opposite happens.

However, in Chrome, when given focus, it rises to **328px**, and then drops back to **256px** width. If focus is given again, it rises to **284px**, then drops to **212px**, etc etc. until the input is barely visible.

It seems to rise by 28px in width, then drops back by 72px. What is happening here?

**EDIT:** [Here's a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b7RR6/), showing the same problem in Chrome, no problem in Firefox nor Opera.

Comment: Could you please create a fiddle? jsfiddle.net

Comment: @Mr.Bombastic, JSFiddle posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per James Montagne's suggestion, I removed the attribute `type="search` from my input and it works fine. Browsers are terribly inconsistent at styling them.

Answer (score 1):

Use `outerWidth` instead:

http://jsfiddle.net/b7RR6/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input:not([type="checkbox"], .button, .noanimate)').focus(function() {
    $(this).stop(true, true).animate({
        width: $(this).outerWidth() + 50,
    }, 300);
  });

  $('input:not([type="checkbox"], .button, .noanimate)').focusout(function() {
    $(this).stop(true, true).animate({
        width: $(this).outerWidth() - 50,
    }, 300);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is working for this specific input, but it's not working for others that are less stylized (these are now expanding too much and not contracting enough).

Comment: Looks to be related to how webkit handles `type="search"`.  A lot of default styling is added which doesn't seem to factor in properly.

Comment: If you don't need `type="search"` for some reason, I would consider using just a regular input.  It seems browsers are pretty inconsistent at this point in how they treat search input boxes.